# How to CompleteMessage/AbandonMessageAsync in ServiceBus from different process?

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We are designing a system that has two Azure functions (Function A and Function B) in the application. Function A(Timer based) is designed to read messages from the service bus and pass the data to Function B.

Is it possible to CompleteMessage/AbandonMessageAsync the message using LockToken on Function B  instead of waiting for the response from Function B. Function B will be invoking external APIs, so we are looking for a solution to CompleteMessage/AbandonMessageAsync on Function B instead of holding the Function A for the response from Function B?

The goal is to read and lock message from one Azure function and Complete/Abandon the message from a different Azure function.

Answer (score 2):

**For In-process SDK**

To complete a message, a caller must have access to the `MessageReciever` used to retrieve the message. If you can pass the injected receiver to the function B, then you can. With the latest version of Service Bus Extensions (v5) you have `ServiceBusMessageActions` object that can be used instead of a receiver for message settlement.

**For Isolated Worker SDK**

Not possible today.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  We are using the isolated worker SDK, so we will handle the CompleteMessage/AbandonMessageAsync from function A(Caller).

Comment: With the Isolated Worker, you won't be able to. Function A  _execution completion_ is the only way to mark a message as completed.